# IE forces table below navbar (works in Chrome and FF)

Tags: html, css

I apologize up front, I haven't touched this stuff in years so I'm very rusty.

I have a navbar that stays on the left side of the screen.  And a table that is in the center of the page, and it works just fine in Chrome and Firefox.  However in IE, the table is being forced to be beneath the bottom of the navbar.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Here are a couple images describing what is happening:

How it should look:
[Using Chrome and Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmJxF.png)

And in IE: [Using IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyPOk.png)

Here is my CSS sheet:

```
/* The sidebar menu */
        .sidenav {
        height: 100%; /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
        width: 200px; /* Set the width of the sidebar */
        position: fixed; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
        z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
        top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
        left: 0;
        background-color: #dddddd;
        /* overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
        padding-top: 1px;
        }

        /* The navigation menu links */
        .sidenav a {
            padding: 0px 8px 6px 8px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 17px;
            color: #111;
            display: block;
        }

        /* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
        .sidenav a:hover {
            color: #2F7BDC;
        }

        /* Style page content */
        .main {
            margin-left: 200px; /* Same as the width of the sidebar */
            padding: 0px 10px;
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 17px;
            color: #111;
            display: block;
        }

        /* Table Style */
        .error {color: #FF0000;}
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 13px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 50%;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        td, th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
            font-size: 13px;
        }
        .tdright{
            text-align: right;
        }
         tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Side navigation -->
    <div id="nav-placeholder">

    </div>
    <script>
        $.get("navbar.html", function(data){
        $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
        });
    </script>

    <!-- Page content -->

    <div class="main">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
            <center>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><h2><center>Submit Info</h2></center></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="tdright">Comments:</td>
                <td><textarea name="comments" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdright">Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
            </center>

        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

And here is the navbar.html that I am calling:

```
<div class="sidenav">
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/image.jpg" width="180px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><center><h2>Links</h2></center></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a href="comments.php">Submit Comments</a>
<a href="reports.php">Reports</a>
<a href="#">Placeholder 1</a>
<a href="#">Placeholder 2</a>
```

Comment: try setting your `.main` class to `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, that didn't do it.

Comment: hmm, it could also be that you are missing `</div>` tag in your navbar.html

Comment: Ha I accidentally didn't include that when pasting into my post.  Sorry.  But it is in my code.  Edit:  Weird, it is in the post when i go to edit it.  Maybe I hit some limit or something.  Either way, it's there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's your table styling. More specifically, `table {width: 50%;}` is causing the table to expand outside of it's container which forces the `.main` down below it

Comment: I agree it's got to be in my table styling, just not sure what exactly.  So with your suggestion, I tried shrinking it down to like 10%, which makes it super skinny and weird.  But it still doesn't fix it in IE.  Just not sure why it sits at the top fine and happy in Chrome and Firefox, but IE forces it down below my navbar.

Comment: what version of IE?

Comment: 11.  Ironically, it works perfectly in Edge lol.